# Facing issue while integrating Azure Application Insights with Azure API Management instance

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have created an Azure Application Insights instance with the Application Type as General.

But when I try to integrate the Application Insight with an API Management service Instance through Monitoring -> Application Insights -> Add options in APIM instance, I am not getting any data of the Application Insights instances in the dropdown.

This is happening even though the APIM Instance and Application Insights locations are same.

Comment: Which language are you coding in? Second, some code samples, please.

Comment: Do you mean you can not find the app insights instance while integrated with APIM? If yes, there is an [issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/12606) for that, and you need also check with this [suggestion](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/12606#issuecomment-409389666)

Comment: @IvanYang yes, I am not able to find the app insights instances while integrating with APIM instance. As per the suggestion which you have mentioned in your comment, it says that we need to wait for some time for getting the app insights available. But I have created app Insights 3 days back and I tried with all the other different locations as well, but the issue still remains.

Comment: @LathaGottipati, just want to make sure, are they in the same subscription?

Comment: and I can see the newly created application insights instance while configure apim.

Comment: @IvanYang yes, they are in the same subscription, same resource group and same location.

Comment: @LathaGottipati, that's too weird. It's fine at my side. I suggest you can submit a support request by following this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug in the APIM Portal in Azure. To work around, go to 
Directory + Subscription (at the top right corner of the portal window) and select only the subscription under which the App Insight resource was created.

Now, go back and try adding the Application Insights, you will see all the app insight resources that belongs to the selected subscription.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. With the work around which you mentioned I am able to see all the application insights.

Comment: @LathaGottipati - This was a bug in the Microsoft Azure Portal. They have fixed the issue. See the details - https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/35373

Comment: I just experienced this issue. Had to use the solution mentioned above to see the App Insight instance I created in the same subscription and RG as my APIM Instance.